# Programming with C macros

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to solve these exercises:

> 1. Give the exact C code of the statement `a = min1(a, b + + ) ;` after macro processing.
> 2. Give the exact C code of the statement `a = min2 (a, b++) ;` after macro processing.
> 3. Give the exact C code of the statement `if ( b < min)`  after macro processing.
> 4. Assume 60 and -30 are entered as inputs. What is the exact output of the program?
> 5. Assume 50 and 30 are entered as inputs. What is the exact output of the program?

My knowledge of C is slightly beyond introductory and I find macros very confusing. From what I understand, they expand their arguments in a manner similar to substitution?

```
#define minl(x, y) ( (x < y) ? x : y)
#define min 10
#include <stdio.h>

int min2(int x, int y) {
    if (x < y)   
        return x;  
    else     
        return y;
}

main() {
    int a, b;  
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);  
    if (b < min)    
        printf("input out of range\n");  
    else {    
        a = minl(a, b++);    
        printf("a = %d, b %d\n", a, b);    
        a = min2(a, b++);    
        printf("a = %d, b %d\n", a, b);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, in this case they just substitute.  Nothing more complicated than that.  The assignment is to help you explore some of the more unexpected consequences of this.

Comment: `#define minl(x, y) ( (x < y) ? x : y)` -> `#define minl(x, y) ( ((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))` as weird things happen when `x` or `y` are some values that are text replaced as not resulting in what is expected. Consider `min(a += 5, b++`)

Comment: @EdHeal: I was also about to complain about the macro, but I think the point of the assignment is to discover for yourself why it's bad.

Comment: Compile and run the code to see what the exact outputs are. Compile with `-E` to see the code after the preprocessor is done with it.